# Calculating Credit Impulse in R growth of growth

Tags: r, xts, finance, quantmod, economics

Part Finance Part R question

I have been trying to replicate the below formula in R using the Quantmod package and xts also using the diff function. The code gives me a plot for credit impulse but it doesn't seem to be replicating what I am trying to get at. See link

https://www.gam.com/media/1434580/biggs.pdf -

page 2 give the formula for Credit Impulse  - where C is the stock of credit at time t

Credit impulset = (Ct – Ct-1)/GDPt – (Ct-1-Ct-2)/GDPt-1

page 3 take a look at the graph( This is the graph I am trying to replicate for Credit Impulse

Am I using the diff function the right way also could I be doing this more efficiently in R?

below is my code

```
#US DEBT [BN][USD][Q]
usd_debt <- getSymbols("CRDQUSAPABIS", src = "FRED", auto.assign=FALSE)

##US GDP [BN][USD][Q]
usd_gdp <- getSymbols("GDP", src = "FRED", auto.assign=FALSE)

#USD Credit Impulse
usd_debt <- usd_debt["2000/2016"] 
usd_gdp <- usd_gdp["2000/2016"]
usd_ratio <- usd_debt/usd_gdp
usd_ci <- diff(usd_ratio)
plot(usd_ci)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you may actually want to use:

```
z <- diff(diff(usd_debt) / coredata(usd_gdp))
plot(z)
```

assuming `Ct` can be modeling using your `usd_debt` series?

Yes you're using `diff` the right way.  `diff` will call `diff.xts` when you apply it to an xts object, and in your example `usd_ratio` is indeed an xts object, so it will be fast (efficient).

Here, `coredata` is optional but good practice when dividing by xts objects, as it returns the underlying matrix instead.  Division for `xts` objects can be problematic.